# How to alter the scope of transitive maven dependencies in SBT?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, dependency-management

I'm developing a plugin in Scala for Elasticsearch 5.0. 
This means that I have to add the whole Elasticsearch as a dependency as so:

```
...
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "5.0.0"
...
```

If you see [their pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0/elasticsearch-5.0.0.pom) in Maven central, ALL their external dependencies are declared like this (notice the exclusions):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-memory</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

That means if I depend on Elasticsearch 5.0.0, I only depend on their jar but I won't have any of the necessary dependencies in my class path!!

Now:

Why on earth would they "exclude" their dependencies like this??

**Is there a SBT trick that overrides the "exclude" of all the transitive dependencies? i.e. (very pseudo code**)

```
dependencyClasspath := dependencyClasspath.map (dep => dep.copy(exclude = Seq())
```

---

**EDIT:** I clarify: the project compiles OK, but I have missing classes at runtime, here is [my build.sbt and error message](https://gist.github.com/sscarduzio/89b176b969abe870c7ea32b1568ddbff)

Comment: Why do you think you will not have enough dependencies to actually build the elasticsearch? Did you try to build it yourself with the original pom file with all the exclusions? What errors did you get?

Comment: it does build, but when I try to run org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch (from my plugin project in Intellij) the classpath contains the elasticsearch jar, but does not contain the dependencies for it!

Comment: @SimY4: edited with link to a gist